# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS | Gnome Shell Extension Manager not working properly (Settings freezing)

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, 22.04, wayland, gnome-shell-extension

When using Gnome Extension Manager on Ubuntu 22.04LTS, the app freezes every time I open the settings of some extension

I tried to install the app with Snap, apt-get, Flatpak and even tried the Chrome 'Gnome Shell Integration' extension, but nothing has let me change the settings of my installed extensions

[image: When I open Gnome Extension Manager It looks like this]

[image: Right after clicking to the setting icon of any extension, nothing happens]

What can I do for fixing this behavior?

Comment: i don't understand what you meant "tried the Chrome extension"? As for the gnome extension manager; if you are using wayland, logout and try using x11 instead when adjusting your extensions.